# Select from multiple tables using Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I am using Entity Framework. I want to select data from multiple tables in the database having no foreign key  relation like

```
select  
    tOut.columnId, wo.columnType, tIn.* 
from 
    TbaleA tIn,
    TableB tOut,
    TableC wo
where
    1 = 1
    and tIn.columnRefId = tOut.columnGuid
    and tOut.columnId = wo.columnId
```

Is there any solution in Entity Framework for this? I have tried by using include syntax its not working for me ..

Comment: *What* is not working? Please be more specific.

Answer (score 3):

You can join tables even though no foreign key relation exists if you use the query syntax.
It would go something along these lines:

```
var result = from tIn in yourDbContext.TableA
             join tOut in yourDbContext.TableB on tIn.columnRefId equals tOut.columnGuid
             join wo in yourDbContext.TableC on tOut.columnId equals wo.columnId
             select new { tOut.columnId, wo.columnType, TableA = tIn };
```

Comment: it will work, but imho it is an "underutilization" of the ORM. Setting navigation properties seems more in the spririt that just mimic SQL statement.

Answer (score 0):

There are examples for both lambda and query syntax on these links:

[MSDN 101 LINQ Samples (mostly query syntax)](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/101-LINQ-Samples-3fb9811b)

[Nilzor's LINQ 101 Samples - Lambda Style](http://linq101.nilzorblog.com/linq101-lambda.php)

Answer (score 0):

Another solution is to use/add navigation properties to your classes, as for example:

```
class TableA {
    Int32 Id {get; set;}

    //navigation property
    TableB b {get; set;}
}
```

and use them in the query

```
from a in yourDbContext.TableA
select new { a.Id, a.b.columnType}
```

Of course there may be a little configuration (code or annotation) to setup the relations to make them fit the database schema. But you will do this effort once and not for every query.